# Get first element of IxSet query result in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use `IxSet` for database-like purposes, so I've built an index of items and I need to do exact match on some field.

Query operator `(@=)` http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ixset/1.0.2/doc/html/Data-IxSet.html#v:-64--61- returns an `IxSet a` type, but I need only to either get `1` or `0` results. To check if it's `0` results, I do `null` items on that, but how do I get first item?

Due to description of `IxSet` type http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ixset/1.0.5/doc/html/Data-IxSet.html#t:IxSet I don't see any typeclass that has operation like `head` or `fst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found an answer. You should use some available function like getOne http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ixset/1.0.5/doc/html/Data-IxSet.html#v:getOne , for example.

p.s.: I find that a bit strange to first create your type from list of items and then add operations that duplicate list-operations, but maybe I'm just newbie :)